# How much in total did Nazi Germany spend on their war machine

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

How much German marks did Germany spend on there army during WW2.
They had around 13 million soldiers they had to pay them and manufacture there gear.

Answer (score 2):

According to the testimony of Walter Funk, the Reich Economy Minister (*Trial of the Major War Criminals* XIII, 129-130), output for war production was about 260 billion RM within Germany, plus an additional 90 billion RM in the occupied areas. To put this in perspective, production in the Reich from 1941-1943 was approximately 400 billion RM altogether, and about 300 billion RM in the occupied countries.

Funk's figures obviously don't take into account the production generated through slave labour, but that had costs of its own. See Raul Hilberg (*Destruction of the European Jews* III, 1003-1007) for a brief but interesting discussion of Reich economics in light of the various economic gains and losses incurred by the Holocaust. His conclusion, that economic factors played very little role in the destruction of the Jews, has most recently been challenged by David Cesarani (*The Final Solution*).

[My quote above, from Walter Funk, was cited in Hilberg, 1007n]

Comment: Are these annual figures?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - No, both sets of figures (amount generated and outlay) are for the entire war.

Comment: Entire war? 1941-1943 is not quite the entire war. Maybe limit the comment to that period? Or only one set was for the entire war?

Comment: @TomAu. Correct - apologies (too late to edit the comment). Funk's testimony relates to the entire war, but Hilberg's observations on production relate to the war against the Soviet Union only, and only until '43.