# How Much Did World War Two Cost Financially?

Tags: world-war-two

Allowing for inflation, what was the total cost for the entire war?

I am interested in totals for all countries involved, all war-related manufacturing, mobilisation, man-power, consumables etc.

Comment: How about the cost of destruction? E.g., should rebuilding European and Japanese infrastructure be included?

Comment: We can't afford another.

Comment: Theoretically possible to assemble the total value of goods and services produced for the war.  Not possible to measure the opportunity cost - the number of doctors/lawyers/plumbers/steelworkers/ whose production was diverted to military use or who died and never produced again.  Not possible to measure the opportunity cost resulting from the changes in society.  tl:dr - we can give you a number, but the number has no meaning, there is no way to establish whether my guess is better than @sds ' guess, etc.  Why do you want to know?

Answer (score 4):

This is a [quora-worthy](https://www.quora.com/How-much-money-did-World-War-II-cost) question: the way it is asked, no direct answer will make the reader any wiser.  E.g., the US WW2 cost was $296B (current), which is [FY2011$4,104B](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/natsec/RS22926.pdf) or [FY2008$4,114B](https://www.history.navy.mil/research/library/online-reading-room/title-list-alphabetically/c/costs-major-us-wars.html) (apparently, we experienced deflation in 2008-2011 - I did not notice).

[WW2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II) was a major historical event, and ascribing it a price tag ([monty python](https://youtu.be/zduKIF5Mo0k?t=1m40s)) makes about as much sense as saying something like "*19th century cost was $X*". Moreover, from the historical perspective, [WW2 is inseparable from WW1](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/11072/1979) - we need to attach a price tag to 35 years of human history.

WW2 involved a lot of unproductive expense - weapons, ammo, &c. It involved a lot of destruction; Germany, European Russia, Japan were pretty much devastated. [~70M people died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties) (give or take 10-20% - we will probably never know how many people in China and Russia died).

During the war and its *aftermath* (you don't think that in 1945 everyone got back home to live in peace, do you?) [millions of people were displaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_evacuation_and_expulsion).

At the same time WW2 spurred a lot of [technological progress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_during_World_War_II) (nukes, radars, rockets, jets), and we are both reaping benefits and paying costs of those changes even now.

An [unprecedented](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/28760/1979) Eastern [migration of Soviet industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evacuation_in_the_Soviet_Union) changed the face of Siberia.

[Shipbuilding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_ship) was revolutionized.

Role of [women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_World_War_II) all over the world dramatically expanded.

[Higher education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.I._Bill) became more accessible.

Now, put $$$ cost/benefit on this...

PS. A more limited [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/35484/1979) may actually make sense.